# Grouping timestamps by interval between timestamps, then calculating from group MySQL

Tags: mysql, timestamp

To put this question into context, I'm trying to calculate "time in app" based on an event log.

Assume the following table:

```
user_id   event_time
2         2012-05-09 07:03:38
3         2012-05-09 07:03:42
4         2012-05-09 07:03:43
2         2012-05-09 07:03:44
2         2012-05-09 07:03:45
4         2012-05-09 07:03:52
2         2012-05-09 07:06:30
```

I'd like to get the difference between the highest and lowest `event_time` from a set of timestamps that are within 2 minutes of eachother (and grouped by user).  If a timestamp is outside of a 2 minute interval from the set, it should be considered a part of another set.

Desired output:

```
user_id  seconds_interval
2        7     (because 07:03:45 - 07:03:38 is 7 seconds)
3        0     (because 07:03:42)
4        9     (because 07:03:52 - 2012-05-09 07:03:43)
2        0     (because 07:06:30 is outside 2 min interval of 1st user_id=2 set)
```

This is what I've tried, although I can't group on `seconds_interval` (even if I could, I'm not sure this is the right direction):

```
SELECT (max(tr.event_time)-min(tr.event_time)) as seconds_interval
FROM some_table tr
INNER JOIN TrackingRaw tr2 ON (tr.event_time BETWEEN 
   tr2.event_time - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AND tr2.event_time + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) 
GROUP BY seconds_interval
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a very straightforward way of querying your existing table to produce the data you want.  However, you could maintain a second table of user sessions (of course this has the disadvantage that if you later want a report that uses a different session timeout period, you will need to repopulate the table from scratch):

```
CREATE TABLE Sessions (
  user_id INT,
  session_start TIMESTAMP,
  session_end   TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, session_start),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id, session_start) REFERENCES TrackingRaw(user_id, event_time),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id, session_end  ) REFERENCES TrackingRaw(user_id, event_time)
);
```

You can automatically populate/update such a table with a trigger that uses `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_TrackingRaw AFTER INSERT ON TrackingRaw FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO Sessions (user_id, session_start, session_end)
    SELECT NEW.user_id,
           IFNULL(MAX(session_start), NEW.event_time),
           NEW.event_time
    FROM   Sessions
    WHERE  user_id = NEW.user_id
       AND session_end >= NEW.event_time - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    session_start = session_start,
    session_end   = NEW.event_time;
```

Then, to obtain your desired query results:

```
SELECT user_id, session_end - session_start AS seconds_interval FROM Sessions;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad7f6/1/0).

---

**UPDATE**

After further reflection, you could of course build such a `Sessions` table within a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getSessions(IN secs INT) READS SQL DATA BEGIN
  DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT user_id, event_time FROM TrackingRaw ORDER BY event_time ASC;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

  DROP   TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Sessions;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Sessions (
    user_id INT,
    session_start TIMESTAMP,
    session_end   TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id,session_start),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id,session_start) REFERENCES TrackingRaw(user_id,event_time),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id,session_end  ) REFERENCES TrackingRaw(user_id,event_time)
  );

  OPEN cur;
  the_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO @u, @t;
    IF no_more_rows THEN
      CLOSE cur;
      LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO Sessions
      SELECT @u, IFNULL(MAX(session_start), @t), @t
      FROM   Sessions
      WHERE  user_id = @u AND session_end >= @t - secs
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      session_start = session_start, session_end = @t
  END LOOP the_loop;

  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  SELECT user_id, session_end - session_start AS seconds_interval FROM Sessions;
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE Sessions;
END;;
```

And then to obtain your output:

```
CALL getSessions(120); -- for a 2 minute (120 second) timeout
```